# How to convert csv file content to DataTable?

Tags: vb.net, csv

I convert CSV file to DataTable using following code. It is working fine but sometimes it adds invalid character between the string.

```
Private Shared Function convertToDT(filePath As String) As DataTable
    Dim detailDataTable As New DataTable()
    Using csvReader As New TextFieldParser(filePath)
        csvReader.SetDelimiters(New String() {","})
        csvReader.HasFieldsEnclosedInQuotes = True
        Dim colFields As String() = csvReader.ReadFields()

        For Each column As String In colFields
            Dim datecolumn As New DataColumn(column.ToLowerInvariant)
            datecolumn.AllowDBNull = True
            detailDataTable.Columns.Add(datecolumn)
        Next

        While Not csvReader.EndOfData
            Dim rowData As String() = csvReader.ReadFields  //sometimes rowData convert invalid name
            For i As Integer = 0 To rowData.Length - 1
                //perform operation
            Next
            If rowData IsNot Nothing AndAlso rowData(0) IsNot Nothing Then
                If Not (rowData(0).StartsWith("#") Or String.IsNullOrEmpty(rowData(0))) Then
                    detailDataTable.Rows.Add(rowData)
                End If
            End If
        End While
    End Using
    Return detailDataTable
End Function
```

[image]
Sometime it add invalid name. Can anybody please suggest

Comment: can you include a line or two from the raw csv which fails?

Comment: That's an encoding problem. Save the file as UTF-8 and it will probably resolve it.

Comment: @Crowcoder It's excel file. I simply save it as .csv file. How can I apply UTF-8 for it?

Comment: @Plutonix `detailDataTable.Rows.Add(rowData)` in above code adds rowData to data table. In between I just check few condition of null or empty or trim like `rowData(i) = Trim(rowData(i))` in for loop

Comment: @NanjiMange, http://help.meetedgar.com/article/107-help-how-do-i-export-my-spreadsheet-to-a-utf-8-encoded-csv